# Setting file directory in appSettings of an app.config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, app-config

Currently I'm hard coding this file location like so

```
   var appleCert = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "../../../Resources/PushSharp.Apns.Sandbox.p12"));
```

What I'd like to do is the somehow change that line to `var appleCert = somevariablehere;`
And I'd like it so that in my AppSettings section of the app.config file contacts the location or is able to find it. Is this possible? If so would anyone care to help me on how to implement this in appSettings?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Sorry, thanks a lot John!

Comment: If this is an ASP.NET application, then it uses web.config, not app.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you want.  But personnaly if I have a file path I would put it in a key value in my web.config:

```
  <appSettings>
        <add key="UploadPath" value="C:\temp" />
  </appSettings>
```

I normally Have a ConfigurationManager class that have each app setting value into this class like that:

```
public class ConfigurationManager
{
    public string UploadPath
    {
        get
        {
            return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadPath"];
        }
    }
}
```

It's also very useful when you have unit test so you can mock your class.

I don't use static class because I'm using dependency injection.. but if you are not and you don't have unit test, you can set your class as static